# Create default custom class in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Every time I create a new class in Xcode, I would like it to have some personal structure.

Is it possible to create a default option, so every time I open the `new file` window, I will see my own class option ?

For example,I will have there :  `myClass.Swift` , which will look like this :

```
import UIKit

class customView: UIView {

    override init (frame : CGRect)
    {

        super.init(frame : frame)

       //some view
       //some vars
    }

    convenience init () {
        self.init(frame:CGRect.zero)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
    }

}
```

If not, is there any other option to get a similar effect ?

Comment: http://swiftandpainless.com/creating-a-smart-file-template/ ?

Comment: Yes. Well, when you use the word template google brings much better results. I somehow didn't find it. Thanks .

Comment: You were indeed missing the key word "template" which is what you are looking for.